# Import error catkin_pkg while importing rosbag, roslib and rospy

Tags: ros, rosbag, catkin, rospy, roslib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am novice to ROS and I followed the ROS installation tutorial to install ROS kinetic. After installing, I open python to import rospy, roslib and rosbag, but it throws the following error:

> 

```
import roslib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    import roslib.stacks
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/stacks.py", line 46, in <module>
    import roslib.packages
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/packages.py", line 49, in <module>
    from catkin.find_in_workspaces import find_in_workspaces as catkin_find
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/find_in_workspaces.py", line 36, in <module>
    from catkin_pkg.packages import find_packages
ImportError: No module named catkin_pkg.packages
```

I again installed catkin_pkg using the following command but nothing happened:

```
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-catkin-pkg
```

Can anyone suggest me where I am going wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273672/import-error-catkin_pkg-while-importing-rosbag,-roslib-and-rospy/) by [Ashutosh Mishra](https://answers.ros.org/users/32334/ashutosh-mishra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-10-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-20**:
Please tell us how you installed ROS: using `apt-get` or building from sources, on which Linux distribution this is and which "ROS installation tutorial" you followed (link).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-20**:
Also: do you `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` before starting the `python` interpreter?

**Comment by [Ashutosh Mishra](https://answers.ros.org/users/32334/ashutosh-mishra/) on 2017-10-20**:
Yes I did source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash and I followed the following link for installation: http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2017-10-20**:
Please post the output of `python -c "import catkin_pkg; print(catkin_pkg.__file__)"`.

**Comment by [Ashutosh Mishra](https://answers.ros.org/users/32334/ashutosh-mishra/) on 2017-10-20**:
Thanks a lot, this link helped me https://answers.ros.org/question/126471/cmake-failed-catkin_pkg/, particularly installing pip install catkin_pkg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the comments on the referenced question mention you should *not* install catkin_pkg via pip. This is why you have the problem in the first place. And when the next version is released as a Debian package you will have the same problem again since your old pip package overlays the new Debian pkg.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2017-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1